# Constraints when creating a Genotype using Jenetics

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, jenetics

I am experimenting with the Multi-objective Optimization Problem (MOP) using [Jenetics](http://jenetics.io/). A toy problem I created is to select two subsets from a given set, maximizing their total sum, given each subset has a limit.
However I want to ensure that the two subsets are mutually exclusive. How can I set this constraint when creating Genotype of the two Chromosomes?

The set I'm using for my toy problem is:

```
private static final ISeq<Integer> SET = ISeq.of( IntStream.rangeClosed( 1, 10 )
            .boxed()
            .collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
```

The signature of my problem is:

```
Problem<List<ISeq<Integer>>, BitGene, Vec<int[]>>
```

And the codec is:

```
@Override public Codec<List<ISeq<Integer>>, BitGene> codec() {
        Objects.requireNonNull( SET );
        final Genotype<BitGene> g =
                Genotype.of( BitChromosome.of( SET.length() ), BitChromosome.of( SET.length() ) );
        return Codec.of(
                g,
                gc -> gc.stream().map( z -> z.as( BitChromosome.class ).ones().mapToObj( SET )
                        .collect( ISeq.toISeq() ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() )
        );
    }
```

I have assigned the first subset with a limit of 9 and the second subset with a limit of 4.

I expect an initial population of two chromosomes with mutually exclusive genes such that Phenotype's in the end will yield individuals that do not have items duplicated from the `SET`.

An example output I'm currently getting is:

```
[[4,5], [4]]
```

But I expect both individuals to have mutually exclusive items. How can this be achieved with Jenetics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the only possible encoding of your problem, since every problem has its own characteristics. For a *Multi Knapsack Problem* I would choose an `IntegerChromosome` instead of a `BitChromosomes`.

```
private static final ISeq<Integer> ITEMS = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
    .boxed()
    .collect(ISeq.toISeq());

public Codec<ISeq<List<Integer>>, IntegerGene> codec(final int knapsackCount) {
    return Codec.of(
        Genotype.of(IntegerChromosome.of(
            0, knapsackCount, ITEMS.length())
        ),
        gt -> {
            final ISeq<List<Integer>> knapsacks = IntStream.range(0, knapsackCount)
                .mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<Integer>())
                .collect(ISeq.toISeq());

            for (int i = 0; i < ITEMS.length(); ++i) {
                final IntegerGene gene = gt.get(0, i);
                if (gene.intValue() < knapsackCount) {
                    knapsacks.get(gene.intValue()).add(ITEMS.get(i));
                }
            }

            return knapsacks;
        }
    );
}
```

The codec given above chooses an `IntegerChromoses` with the length of the number of Knapsack items. Its gene range will be bigger than the number of Knapsacks. Item *i* will be put into the Knapsack with the chromosome index of `IntegerChromosome.get(0, i).intValue()`. If the index is out of the valid range, the item is skipped. This encoding will guarantee a distinct division of the items.

Comment: This is prefect. I can easily extend this approach for other problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a distinct set of genes, you have to define two distinct sets.

```
private static final ISeq<Integer> SET1 = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
    .boxed()
    .collect(ISeq.toISeq());

private static final ISeq<Integer> SET2 = IntStream.rangeClosed(11, 20)
    .boxed()
    .collect(ISeq.toISeq());


public Codec<ISeq<ISeq<Integer>>, BitGene> codec() {
    return Codec.of(
        Genotype.of(
            BitChromosome.of(SET1.length()),
            BitChromosome.of(SET2.length())
        ),
        gt -> ISeq.of(
            gt.getChromosome(0).as(BitChromosome.class).ones()
                .mapToObj(SET1)
                .collect(ISeq.toISeq()),
            gt.getChromosome(1).as(BitChromosome.class).ones()
                .mapToObj(SET2)
                .collect(ISeq.toISeq())
        )
    );
}
```

With the two integer sets you will have guaranteed the distinctiveness.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. So I take that having distinct sets is the only way to generate distinct set of genes. I will accept this answer. 
Could you also suggest what kind of approach I would need to take in order to solve the _Multiple Knapsack Problem_ as a _Multi-objective problem_ with the `jenetics.ext` module? This poses a similar question that I need to fill multiple knapsacks with a distinct set of items from a given finite set of items, satisfying the maximum weight condition. In this case, it isn't feasible to have two distinct sets.